# Open *.data files as greyscale images in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I am trying to open a greyscale image in *.data format in GIMP, but the only options that I get are multichannel (RGB, RGB alpha, etc.). Is there a way to change this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: Well, I basically opened a grayscale jpg in text (or notepad) and saved it as *.data, which is one of the native Gimp extensions for raw data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`File`->`Open`

Choose `Raw image data` as the file type and find your `.data` file and open it.

In the proceeding `Load Image From Raw Data` dialog, set the `Image Type` to `Indexed`. Set the `Offset` to `0` and the `Width` and `Height` to the correct dimensions for your data. Leave everything under the `Palette` section as defaults.

Answer (score -2):

Open in RGB and change `Image` > `Mode` > `Greyscale`?

Comment: The problem is that if I open in RGB I distribute the data in 3 channels, creating a reduced size file. I want to keep the entire data in a single channel.